# inserting values in edittext with custom keyboard

Tags: android

I work on an application where I have 9 edittext and a custom keyboard I want when I type a number in a selected edittext the number will be well written for example if I want to write 12 in my edittext1 it will be 21 and I also want the number do not repeat in other edittext for example if the value that I give to edittext1 is 11 this 11 when I try to type another time in the remaining 8 edittext do nothing. I try with a code but when I type 1 in edittext1 and I try to type 11 in edittext 2 nothing does is an animation it tells me that 1 repeats here is the code that I use

```
public void editTextWatcher(final EditText edt) {
    edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, 
   int after) {

        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            edt.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            edt.setText("");
            edt.addTextChangedListener(this);

            ArrayList<String> texts = new ArrayList<String>();
            texts.add(et1.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et2.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et3.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et4.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et5.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et6.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et7.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et8.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et9.getText().toString());

            for (String text : texts) {
                if (s.toString().equals(text)) {
                    if (s.toString().equals("")) {
                        return;
                    }

                    AlphaAnimation animation1 = new AlphaAnimation(0.2f, 1.0f);
                    animation1.setDuration(70);
                    animation1.setStartOffset(500);
                    animation1.setFillAfter(true);
                    edt.startAnimation(animation1);
                    edt.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                    edt.addTextChangedListener(this);
                    afficheerr1();

                    return;

                } 
            }

            edt.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            edt.setText(s.toString());
            edt.addTextChangedListener(this);

        }
    });
```

and the code in onCreate

```
    editTextWatcher(et1);
    editTextWatcher(et2);
    editTextWatcher(et3);
    editTextWatcher(et4);
    editTextWatcher(et5);
    editTextWatcher(et6);
    editTextWatcher(et7);
    editTextWatcher(et8);
    editTextWatcher(et9);
```

I try several times but I can not find the solution I want .....

Comment: why are you showing animation?

Comment: because if 9 in Edittext1 and I try to enter 9 in Edittext2, Edittext 2 does not accept 9 because it is in Edittext1 and does a little animation

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as -
first put your all EditText in an array as -

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
     private EditText[] editTextsList;

     void oncreate(){
     ....
     EditText editTex1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt1);
     EditText editTex2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt2);
     ...
     EditText editTex9 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt9);
     // put your all editText in array
    editTextsList = new EditText[]{editTex1, editTex2, ..., editTex9};
     ....
     ....
     // add text watcher to each Edit Text
      for (EditText edt : editTextsList) {
       edt.addTextWatcher(edt);
      }

     }
 private void addTextWatcher(final EditText editText) {
    TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            boolean isDuplicate = checkText(editText);
            if(isDuplicate){
                editText.setText("");
                // do your animation
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    };
    editText.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
}

// check is text available in other EditText
private boolean checkText(EditText editText) {
    for (EditText edt : editTextsList) {

        if (editText.getId() != edt.getId()) {

            if (edt.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(editText.getText().toString())) {
                return true;
            }

        }
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

This may help you

Comment: Thank you but it shows me an error "edt.add TextWatcher (edt);" it will be red